# How can versions earlier that macOS Sierra ignore the .ssh_config UseKeychain option?

Tags: macos, ssh, osx-yosemite, macos-sierra

I am sharing my ssh_config between a sierra macbook and machines with earlier versions, ie Yosemite. But when it reads UseKeychain yes, it considers it a missconfiguration.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Match` blocks in the `ssh_config` to differentiate between OS versions, for example:

```
# or some other condition that is true only on your new systems
Match exec ssh -V | grep -v OpenSSH_6
  UseKeychain yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IgnoreUnknown`:

```
IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
UseKeychain yes
```

I found that information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html